# remove user id from array of object ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have four object ids in an array . i also have a user id. i would like to remove the user id from array of object ids

```
allowners= [ 5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d, 5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b, 
5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8, 5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d]
user._id = 5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d
```

what i tried

```
  const userid = user._id
  const vendors = allowners.filter((item) => userid !== item)
```

The result i got is

```
  vendors = [ 5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d,
     5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b,
     5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8,
     5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d ]
```

the result i am expecting is

```
    vendors = [ 5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b,5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8]
```

Comment: Are these `allowners` array of ids returned from mongoose and `user._id` a string?

Comment: maybe: `const vendors = allowners.filter((item) => user._id !== item)`?

Comment: i used flat map
const allowners = chatrooms.flatMap(room => room.owners) 
to get owners ids of two chat rooms into one. @ambianBeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these ids in `allowners` array are `Mongoose ObjectID` you'll need to use **[.equals](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/ObjectID.html#equals)** method on the ObjectID object to compare:

```
user._id = "5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d"; //even if this is an ObjectID of mongoose
const userid = user._id;
const vendors = allowners.filter(item => !item.equals(userid));
```

**Another Way:** Using **[toString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/)** on ObjectID (will only work when compared to a string -- userid)

```
vendors = allowners.filter(item => item.toString() !== userid);
```

**Output:**

```
console.info("Filtered IDs::", vendors);
Filtered IDs:: [ 5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b, 5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8 ]
```

Comment: hi can you please explain why we have to use  !item.equals instead of !=

Comment: @vithushaji Because as I susupected/assumed and you know: Ids in `allowners` are not simple strings but object of type `ObjectID` from mongo/mongoose & u can't compare Object with string right. So it exposes a method `.equals` to compare. Also the other method is `toString()`, updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your result should compute to the expected result if your data type match properly. For example:

```
// Your array of IDs of type {String}
const allowners = ['5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d', '5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b', '5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8', '5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d'];

// Your user object with an id of type {String}
const userObject = {
    id: '5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d'
}

// Extract the id from your user object, and store in a userId variable If you wish :-)
const userId = userObject.id;

// Using your code with just changes in the variable name (userid -> userId)
const vendors = allowners.filter((item) => userId !== item);

// The result
console.log(vendors); // [ '5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b', '5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8' ]
```